# Google Maps: Multiple companies on one location

Tags: google, google-maps

I'm making some websites, and a few of those are for different companies at the same address (we offer different services under different names).

Usually for a company's website I use the hCard format to get Google to show a map of the location when people search for the company. As far as I know this also makes the company name appear on the map itself.

However, because several companies are running from the same building, we don't want to confuse our customers and just show the main company name on the map. Is it possible to somewhere set a preference as to which name to show on a map, but still have Google serve up maps as SERPs for each of the company names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would take a look at Google Places you could claim for each business and customise the information. this would then be used as the default in maps and you could just re-enforce that by using the hCard format on the website.

i have not seen anything that allows you to explicitly set a default business though. I would guess though depending on the search terms used different maps results get set any way and you would therefore only really compete on an exact match for the location.